# SAFE FME: How to iterate through Featureclasses in a GDB and write their Filename to an attribute in a separate featureclass

Tags: fme-form, file-geodatabase

I have a GDB which contains raster datasets and Vector featureclasses .
Each Featureclass contains only one polygon. The Polygon represents project areas whose name is also the title of the featureclasse e.g "BP_2247"

In the Featureclass itself this name is not written to an attribute.
I therefore want to merge all featureclasses together whilst also writing their filename into a new attribute in the merge file.

My first problem is how to get Safe FME to iterate through a GDB and only use Featureclasses?

Comment: add from the format attributes [in Feature Type Properties] geodb_feature_dataset should give you the attribute needed using the Geodatabase ArcObjects Reader (not geodb open api)

Comment: Thanks. But can I simply iterate through all Datasets somehow instead of getting 150 individual readers?

Comment: You can use Single Merged Feature Type when adding them all will show as one reader.

Comment: You could use a schema reader. [http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/Default.htm#schema/schema.htm%3FTocPath%3DFME%20Readers%20and%20Writers%20(formats%20supported%20by%20FME%202014)%7CSchema%20(Any%20Format)%20Reader%7C_____0](Documentation) [http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Geodatabase-XML-Workspace-Document-Schema-Reader](example)